# pacman -S network-manager network-manager-applet reports an invalid or corrupted package

Tags: networkmanager, pacman

I'm installing archlinux32 on a Fujitsu Siemens Amilo old laptop.
When trying to install network-manager I get the following error:

> Blockquote

error: libdatrie: signature from "TasosSah (Arch32 Package Signing Key) arch32@tasossah.com is unknown trust. File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/libdatrie-0.2.13-4.0-pentium4.pkg.tar.zst is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).
Do you want to delete it? y/n

> Blockquote

It doesn't matter if I answer yes or no, either way I get the following error:

> Blockquote

error:failed to commit transaction (invalid or corrupted package)
Errors occurred,no packages were upgraded.

> Blockquote